# Sum duplicate values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set with this structure:

```
col A   
 11
 11
 9
 9 
 9
 7
 7
 2
 11
 11
 7
 7
```

I would like to sum up all group repeating entries in column A. In other words, I want to add 11+9+7+2+11+7 without adding a helper column. I already tried the following formula:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A1:A12,A1:A12),A1:A12))
```

This formula omits ALL repeating values. I only would like to omit GROUPS of repeating data. I want the sum to equal 47.

I also tried:

```
=IF(NOT(A1=A2),SUM(A1:A12),0)
```

Then summing down the column but I would rather have one concise formula as I cannot add another column to my sheet.

Does anyone know a way to sum the group repeating numbers?
Thank you.

Comment: You can't add a helper column?

Comment: GreenWeenie, no, for this sheet I am trying to find a way to do the sum without adding a helper. pnuts, I am trying to do exactly what formula 2 does but only without the helper column.

Comment: It took me a bit to troubleshoot the array formula I was writing.  It is easier with a helper column, but my formula should work for a generic column of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((OFFSET(A2,0,0,COUNT(A:A),1)<>OFFSET(A2,-1,0,COUNT(A:A),1))*OFFSET(A2,0,0,COUNT(A:A),1))
```

Covers if you add additional rows of data.

**EDIT**

Based on comment from @Jerry regarding OFFSET being volitile, I have revised the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:INDEX(A:A,1+COUNT(A:A))<>A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A)))*A2:INDEX(A:A,1+COUNT(A:A)))
```

Comment: Perfect, you are an excel genius!  Thank you very much!

Comment: @JohnAugust Be very careful with that formula. `OFFSET` can take care of additional rows, but if your dataset grows, it can be a problem. `OFFSET` is a volatile function and will recalculate with *any* changes in the workbook.

Comment: Good point @Jerry.  I've revised the formula to stay generic, and allow for expansion.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array formula like this:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A12=A2:A13,0,A1:A12))
```

Entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Or with `SUMPRODUCT` to do the condition:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A12<>A2:A13)*A1:A12)
```